# DafaultTableModel reading in from a file to setValueAt(value, row, col) Java

Tags: java, swing, file, defaulttablemodel

I am using a DefaultTableModel to display a simple user stats page. I have successfully saved the data to a file but am having trouble reading it back in (see`loadData()`method down the bottom). So, what I need it to do is, when I start my program, it reads the file, sets the values to the model and displays the existing data in the table (which is in a JPanel).
here is my code, it just looks 'wrong', but I'm not sure where. Can anyone give me a heads up? Thanks IA

```
public class Statistics extends JPanel {
    public Object[][] data;
    public DefaultTableModel model;
    public PrintWriter saveStats;

public Statistics() {
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));
    String[] columnNames = {"Name", "Games Played", "Games Won"};
    Object[][] data = {};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setVisible(true);
    table.setEnabled(false);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);
}

public void addRow(Object[] objects) {
    model.addRow(objects);

}

public void updateGamesPlayed(String userFolderName, int gamesPlayed) {
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
    int columnCount = model.getColumnCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++){
            if (model.getValueAt(i,j) == userFolderName){
                int count = (Integer) model.getValueAt(i, j+1);
                count += gamesPlayed;
                model.setValueAt(gamesPlayed, i, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    saveGameStats(model);
}

public void saveGameStats(DefaultTableModel model){
    this.model = model;

    File gameStats;
    try {
        gameStats = new File("GameStats.txt");


    System.out.print(gameStats);

    saveStats = new PrintWriter(gameStats);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++){
            saveStats.print(model.getValueAt(i,j)+ " ");
        }
    }
    saveStats.close();
}

public void loadData() {
    String name = "";
    int games = 0;
    int won = 0;
    Scanner loadData = new Scanner("GameStats.txt");
    while(loadData.hasNextLine()){
        if (loadData.hasNext()){
              name = loadData.next();}
            else if (loadData.hasNextInt()){
              games = loadData.nextInt();}
            else if (loadData.hasNextInt()){
              won = loadData.nextInt();}
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++){
                model.setValueAt(name,i,j);
                model.setValueAt(games, i, j+1);
                model.setValueAt(won, i, j+2);
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you a few tips:

- As pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537533/setvalueatobject-avalue-int-row-int-col/19537682#19537682) you still have a class variable `data` which is hidden by a local variable.
- Note you don't need `Object[][] data` anyway. You can just initialize your `DefaultTableModel` in this way: `model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);` and add rows like this: `model.addRow(row)`, where `row` is an `Object[]`.
- Consider use a `SwingWorker` to load data from a file to your table model. Take a look to this example: [Simple Background Tasks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)
- Consider use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) instead of `Scanner` to read the file using [readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method. I can infer from your code that each line of your file is a row in your table. Get the line, [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) this string by whitespaces (you'll get a `String[]`) and add the result to your model: `model.addRow()`

Answer (score 1):

**First issue:**
Inside `loadValue()` function while you were trying to load data, the following code-fragment is not working at all:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++){
            model.setValueAt(name,i,j);
            model.setValueAt(games, i, j+1);
               // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception when j = 2
            model.setValueAt(won, i, j+2); // same exception

        }
    }
```

The reason that you will get AIOutOfB-EX is that, if you have `3` column you will need to access them index: `0-2` inclusive. You don't need this `for` loop at all. Try saving your data row by row, and load them row by row, you have already a function: `addRow(Object[] objects)`, use it.

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{name, games, won})
```

`games` and `won` are instance of Integer.

**Second issue**: `Data[][]` local to `Statistics()` is hiding your field member `Data[][]` declared in the context of the class.  And using [`DefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames, int rowCount)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20int%29) constructor for creating model is preferable. For an empty table `rowCount` is `0`;

**Third Issue:** Save(or load) your data in another thread and updates Swing table from there. Handling this task is not really easy. `SingWorker` is your friend here. Check out the tutorial: [**`Worker Threads and SwingWorker`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough explanation, I'll look into SwingWorker :-)